# I copied someone's files, how do I push it to git

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm not very savvy on "git lingo" so excuse me if I use the wrong terms.

I wasn't able to clone (copy a project to my machine) so I am working off files emailed to me. The project already has a git folder but naturally they have the senders credentials and settings. If I try to commit then push (put it back onto the repository) it tries to do so as the original sender and asks me for his password. How do I "make it mine", in other words how to I make it so its being committed and pushed by me and asking for my password?

I've poked around some of the files under the .git folder and tried to make it "mine" but it still asks for his password.

Comment: What does this have to do with `c` ?

Comment: I guess not much, I'm programming in c and probably should have excluded the tag.

Comment: This site isnt really for general software help

Answer (score 0):

The git remote URL probably contains the original username included. You can change the existing remote URL or add a new git remote that you can use to push ([Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) or [Adding a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/))